# How to use a select between stdin and a socket?

Tags: c, sockets, select

I'm trying to make a chat-like program in c, the main problem is that i do not want to use threads, so for that i need to use select to keep track of the incoming messages from the socket, and of my stdin.

I've already done some search on how to make the select, the socket part seems to be alright, but i can't get the stdin correctly.

```
    fd_set read_fds;
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &read_fds);
    FD_SET(sock_fd, &read_fds);
    while(1){
        select(sock_fd+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if(FD_ISSET(sock_fd, &read_fds) != 0) {
          printf("Entered case for receive message\n");
          char buf[4096];
          memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
          int lastBit;

          lastBit = recv(sock_fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
          if (lastBit > 0 && lastBit < 4096)
          {
            buf[lastBit] = '\0';
          }
          else
          {
            close(sock_fd);
            //break;
          }
          printf("%s\n", buf);
        } else if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &read_fds)) {
          printf("Entered case for send message\n");
          char msg[4096];
          memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
          read(0, msg, sizeof(msg));
        }
    }
```

With this I would expect when i received a new message from the server the message is printed (that is ok), and when a input something, the code should send it to my server (still not ok).

Comment: You need to move the FD_SET calls inside the loop. Your test for end of stream is incorrect. You are ignoring both the result and the data returned by reading the standard input, and you certainly aren't sending any message at this point despite the comment.

Comment: okay i moved then inside the loop, but how exactly do i read from something else then the standard input?

Comment: I hope you also moved the `FD_ZERO`. warning you can have data on several fd, replace `else if` by `if`

Comment: "the code should send it to my server (still not ok)." Where is this sending part supposed to happen? You only read into a `msg` buffer but where do you send it?

Comment: Side note:  select()-ing on stdin won’t work under Windows.